# EXCEL Indirect() returns #Value

Tags: excel

I have a workbook where a column is removed each month when updated but I want to calculate an aggregate over a fixed range of columns each month. This formula is returning #VALUE! error and I can't figure out why. When I run it through the formula evaluator everything runs until array3 (bolded) which returns the #VALUE! error and errors out the whole thing.

Note that when I created this workbook initially the formula worked, but upon closing and re-opening the workbook the formula has thrown the error.

```vb
{=SUMPRODUCT(IF(INDIRECT("F1:AD1")>=DATE(YEAR(MAX(PIF[Rpt_Date])),1,1),1,0),INDIRECT("F2:AD2"),**INDIRECT("F"&ROW()&":AD"&ROW()))**/$B$2}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `INDEX` instead of `INDIRECT`?
`INDIRECT` can be finicky when used with ranges.

You can simplify the formula and avoid using `INDIRECT` using the `INDEX` function to create a dynamic range reference.

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX($F$1:$AD$1,1):INDEX($F$1:$AD$1,1)>=DATE(YEAR(MAX(PIF[Rpt_Date])),1,1))*(F2:AD2)*(F2:AD2)/$B$2)
```

Comment: The reason I use Indirect is because column F is physically deleted from the workbook when it updates each month and then a new column AD is added. With your formula, I don't think the calculation would account for the newly added AD column each month so the range would progressively shrink right? I think the issue is with the version of Excel actually. I created the workbook using 365 and encountered the error when trying to work in 2016 without realizing it. Must be something that version isn't compatible with. I'll mark my question as closed. Thank you for the assistance

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `OFFSET`, it works better than indirect.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to lie in the version of Excel being used. Workbook and subsequent INDIRECT formula were created using Excel 365. Error was encountered when opening in Office2016. As written, that formula must not be compatible with 2016 version of Excel but works as expected in Office365